# Calculate moving weather stats in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm trying to calculate the days since last rain and the amount of rain in that event for each day in my PostgreSQL table of weather data. I've been trying to achieve this with window functions but the limitation of ranges having to be unbounded has left me a bit stuck on how to proceed.
Here's the query I have so far:

```
SELECT
        station_num,
        ob_date,
        rain,
        max(rain) OVER (PARTITION BY station_num ORDER BY ob_date ASC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as prev_rain_mm,
        '' as days_since_rain --haven't attempted this calculation yet
FROM
        obs_daily_ground_moisture
```

This results in the following:

[image: postgres result]

but I'm trying to achieve something more like this:

[image: needed postgres result (edited manually)]

I feel like all the pieces are there in regards to window functions range & filter and nested queries but I'm not sure how to pull it all together. Also the above data is just a subset of the actual dataset, the entire dataset is just over half a million rows.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't paste an image of code, my code is there available to copy and paste. I posted images of tables. If there is a nice way to get tables into SO please advise. I could have put some sample data & code up with sqlfiddle however at the time of posting the site was down hence I went with uploaded images of the tables because it demonstrated the result I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to group the observations starting from the first occurrence of rain>0 value to the next occurrence of rain>0 value. Thereafter you can use window functions to calculate the needed columns.

```
select 
x.station_num,
x.ob_date, 
max(rain) over(partition by station_num,col) prev_rain,
case when rain > 0 then 0 
else row_number() over(partition by station_num, col order by ob_date)-1 end days_since_rain
from (select t.*,
      sum(case when rain > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by station_num order by ob_date) col 
      from t) x
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/NICQ82445)

Comment: Thanks vkp! that looks to do the job for days since rain (which I hadn't even tackled yet) - but do you have any ideas for getting the previous rain value - my max() window function was as far as I got above

Comment: sure..see the edited version. `col` calculation in the inner query basically groups observations starting from the first occurrence of rain>0 value to the next occurrence of rain>0 value into a single group.

Comment: thanks, I'd just worked out a slightly different way using your code from days_since rain before seeing your edited version

Comment: @vkp, What is `col` ? Would you please give some ref ?

Comment: @TanjimRahman col is the alias for expression `sum(case when rain > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by station_num order by ob_date)` in the from clause subquery

Comment: Oh. I never tried something like this. Missed to see the alias. But is that DBMS Specific?

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
        DECLARE @Rain  AS FLOAT

        UPDATE A
        SET
        @Rain = CASE WHEN A.Rain = 0 THEN @Rain ELSE A.Rain END,
        A.Rain = CASE WHEN @Rain IS NULL OR A.Rain <> 0 THEN A.Rain ELSE @Rain END
        FROM obs_daily_ground_moisture A

        SELECT ob_date, Rain, 
        max(rain) OVER (PARTITION BY station_num ORDER BY ob_date ASC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as prev_rain_mm,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Rain ORDER BY ob_date) - 1  as days_since_rain
        FROM obs_daily_ground_moisture ORDER BY ob_date
```

Comment: OP is using postgresql. Your answer appears to be for MS SQL server